# Resources for searching research internships

Tags: job-search, job, internship, visiting

I'm a master's student in computer science and ML, currently on the lookout for research positions within my field. I'm aware that finding such opportunities can be quite challenging, given the decentralized nature of job postings for research/scientific roles. Unlike the more centralized platforms for industry positions, such as LinkedIn, it seems there's no equivalent "go-to" place for research jobs.

My goal is to find a platform where I can filter opportunities based on criteria such as location, specialization, and perhaps the type of research.

Could anyone share their experiences or recommend websites where I could start my search?

Comment: Are you looking for academic or industry-based internships?